# Android fragment only partially re-rendering

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

For some reason, the UI of my fragments is not correctly re-rendering anymore with the new SDK. This is only the case on Android devices with Android 8.0 or higher.

When changes are made in the UI it seems that only 1 fourth of the screen is actually rerendered. So old items are still visible on the screen, and new items are only rendered in the upper left 1/4th of the screen.

When I start dragging (even just a little bit) the view readjusts and renders completely.

I have added some pictures below to demonstrate what is happening. To make it more clear, I have colored the background of the fragments red and blue, so you can see which part has rerendered. As you can see in picture 2, only a part of the fragment has rendered. In picture 3 after dragging a bit (there are multiple tabs) the fragment is completely rendered.

[1 Before UI update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4kSU.png)

[2 After UI update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVNSC.png)

[3 After UI update and dragging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mw6kA.png)

The layout for my viewpager / tablayout activity is as follows:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        android:fillViewport="false" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

The layout in my fragment is as follows. There are two parts. Only one is visible at a time and the other has visibility GONE. The RelativeLayout with id "step1" starts as VISIBLE and the one with "step2" starts as GONE. When pressing the button "step1" will be set to GONE and "step2" to VISIBLE.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".depot.fragment.StockFragment">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/step1"
    android:background="@color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Kies het pand" />

        <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/radio_group">

        </RadioGroup>

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/footer">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

        <Button
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:id="@+id/button_next"
            android:text="Volgende"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/step2"
    android:background="@color/holo_red_dark"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header_step2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/depot_choice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/Material.header"
            android:text="Kies het pand" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="Klik op de knop rechtersonderin het scherm om scannen te starten." />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tableContainer"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header_step2"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer_step2">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:elevation="6dp"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/accent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_border_color_black_24dp"
            android:id="@+id/floating_qrcode_manual"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/floating_qrcode_scan"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/floating_qrcode_scan"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:elevation="6dp"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/accent"
            android:src="@drawable/qrcode_scan"
            android:id="@+id/floating_qrcode_scan"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/footer_step2">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/divider_light"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

        <Button
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/button_prev"
            android:text="Ander pand kiezen"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Could anyone help me find the problem with this code?

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to track down the problem.

It had nothing to do with the ViewPager. Only there were settings in the AndroidManifest that messed up the re-rendering of fragments after android 8.0.

The settings that caused the problems were the following:

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />
```

Removing these solved the problems.